# C# Constructor cannot call itself

Tags: c#

My problem is I cannot call this keyword for the constructor as shown below.

```
public UnitofWork(IDbTransaction transcation, Action<UnitofWork> onCommitOrRollback)
    : this(transcation, onCommitOrRollback)
{

}
```

[image: “Constructor cannot call itself” error message]

When using `base` instead:

[image: “object does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments” error message]

Can anyone explain me what is the problem occurred for this instance.

And the project is class library in which I have taken a class named `UnitofWork`. Here, `UnitofWork` is a constructor having different parameters passing. These parameters itself will be called again for itself for transaction.

Comment: Are you trying to call a super/base class constructor?

Comment: Try `base` instread of `this` if you inherit from some other class...

Comment: Yes, but i am not calling base just this keyword

Comment: I already tried base but same error

Comment: Who says you should be able to do that?! What do you want to do?

Comment: I am designing myself with own no one said to do sir

Comment: If you want to call a contructor from somewhere else you need to qualify it. Of course here you try to call yourself, which is obviously wrong, just as the error message says...

Comment: Okay thank you for suggestion @TaW

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this? What do you hope to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a constructor that takes an `IDbTransaction` and a `Action<UnitofWork>` and starts by calling the constructor which takes an `IDbTransaction` and a `Action<UnitofWork>`, which is to say itself.

That would then immediately call itself, then immediately call itself, then immediately call itself…

If it was allowed, then one of two things would happen:

1. It would keep doing these calls to itself until there was a `StackOverflowException` that crashed the application.
2. The use of the stack was optimised away, so it just called itself forever in an infinite loop.

Either way, it would be pointless, so it's obviously wrong, so it's good for the compiler to not allow you to do so.

Instead a constructor must either:

1. Use `this` to call a **different** constructor on the same type.
2. Use `base` to call a constructor on the base type.
3. Use neither (which is the same as using `base()` to call a parameterless constructor on the base type.

Comment: Either way, it would be pointless, so it's obviously wrong, so it's good for the compiler to not allow you to do so.
Thank you @Jon Hanna for explaining the mistake. I will stop using this keyword or base keyword and keep as it is without using the keywords.

Once again thank you very much

Comment: NP. It's worth looking at cases where the `base` and `this` keywords are useful, to fill out your knowledge in the area.